# How do I get the current mouse screen coordinates in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mouse-coordinates

How to get current mouse coordination on the screen?
I know only `Mouse.GetPosition()` which get mousePosition of element, but I want to get the coordination without using element.

Comment: Mouse coordinates relative to what? Screen coordinates, relative to a Window?

Comment: I means mouse position on the screen.

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

To follow up on Rachel's answer.
Here's two ways in which you can get Mouse Screen Coordinates in WPF.

1.Using Windows Forms. Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms

```
public static Point GetMousePositionWindowsForms()
{
    var point = Control.MousePosition;
    return new Point(point.X, point.Y);
}
```

2.Using Win32

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct Win32Point
{
    public Int32 X;
    public Int32 Y;
};
public static Point GetMousePosition()
{
    var w32Mouse = new Win32Point();
    GetCursorPos(ref w32Mouse);

    return new Point(w32Mouse.X, w32Mouse.Y);
}
```

Comment: While correct, if you take the raw X and Y coordinates and set the location of a window using them, it will not work properly if your DPI settings are anything but 100% (96dpi).

The last answer to the question has it correct!

Comment: Your comment is completely true and this should not be marked as the correct answer of this question!

Comment: Also this is a Windows Forms answer not a WPF answer.  This is not the answer to the questions.

Answer (score 95):

Or in pure WPF use [PointToScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visual.pointtoscreen).

Sample helper method:

```
// Gets the absolute mouse position, relative to screen
Point GetMousePos() => _window.PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(_window));
```

Comment: "Converts a Point that represents the current coordinate system of the Visual into a Point in screen coordinates.". What does this have to do with mouse position?

Comment: Mouse.GetPosition returns a Point, and PointToScreen converts the point to the screen coordinate.

Comment: Hello @erikH, Could you update the link? It is broken

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Now it is ok again. (msdn has changed something...)

Answer (score 34):

Do you want coordinates relative to the screen or the application?

If it's within the application just use:

```cs
Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);
```

If not, I believe you can add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and use:

```cs
System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition;
```

Comment: It's must be System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition

Comment: `error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Control' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Answer (score 25):

If you try a lot of these answers out on different resolutions, computers with multiple monitors, etc. you may find that they don't work reliably. This is because you need to use a transform to get the mouse position relative to the current screen, not the entire viewing area which consists of all your monitors. Something like this...(where "this" is a WPF window).

```
var transform = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice;
var mouse = transform.Transform(GetMousePosition());

public System.Windows.Point GetMousePosition()
{
    var point = Forms.Control.MousePosition;
    return new Point(point.X, point.Y);
}
```

Comment: Great thanks! I was having issues with High Resolution screens and the transformation seems to be working wonderfully.

Comment: @mdiehl13 No worries :) glad you found my transforms to work okay

Comment: @mdiehl13 Clearly, a lot of people test just the base case. +1 for testing around different resolutions and such. :)

Answer (score 8):

This works without having to use forms or import any DLLs:

```
   using System.Windows;
   using System.Windows.Input;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current mouse position on screen
    /// </summary>
    private Point GetMousePosition()
    {
        // Position of the mouse relative to the window
        var position = Mouse.GetPosition(Window);

        // Add the window position
        return new Point(position.X + Window.Left, position.Y + Window.Top);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You may use combination of TimerDispatcher (WPF Timer analog) and Windows "Hooks" to catch cursor position from operational system.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT pPoint);
```

Point is a light `struct`. It contains only X, Y fields.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DispatcherTimer dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_tick);
        dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0, 50);
        dt.Start();
    }

    private void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        POINT pnt;
        GetCursorPos(out pnt);
        current_x_box.Text = (pnt.X).ToString();
        current_y_box.Text = (pnt.Y).ToString();
    }

    public struct POINT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public POINT(int x, int y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }
    }
```

This solution is also resolving the problem with too often or too infrequent parameter reading so you can adjust it by yourself. But remember about WPF  method overload with one arg which is representing `ticks` not `milliseconds`.

```
TimeSpan(50); //ticks
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a 1 liner, this does well.

```
new Point(Mouse.GetPosition(mWindow).X + mWindow.Left, Mouse.GetPosition(mWindow).Y + mWindow.Top)
```

The `+ mWindow.Left` and `+ mWindow.Top` makes sure the position is in the right place even when the user drags the window around.

Answer (score 1):

`Mouse.GetPosition(mWindow)` gives you the mouse position relative to the parameter of your choice.
`mWindow.PointToScreen()` convert the position to a point relative to the screen.

So `mWindow.PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(mWindow))` gives you the mouse position relative to the screen, assuming that `mWindow` is a window(actually, any class derived from `System.Windows.Media.Visual` will have this function), if you are using this inside a WPF window class, `this` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I wanna use this code

```
Point PointA;
private void Button_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    PointA = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(sender as UIElement);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // use PointA Here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the mouse absolute coordinates (tested on dual 4K screens) in pure WPF for the current window instance ('this')

```
System.Windows.Point  MousePos  =  this.PointToScreen( System.Windows.Input.Mouse.GetPosition(this));
```