# how to GetMousePosition anywhere on the screen, outside the bounds of window (or any Visual)

Tags: wpf

I'd like to track the position of the Mouse cursor, in screen coordinates, anywhere on the screen. So even if the mouse cursor moves outside the bounds of the window, is there a way to get the position of the mouse cursor?

What I'm doing is trying to get a popup to follow the mouse cursor, even if it moves off the main window.

Here is a code snippet of what I've tried (and hasn't worked):

```
        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        bool gotcapture = this.CaptureMouse();
        Mouse.AddLostMouseCaptureHandler(this, this.OnMouseLostCapture);
    }
            Point mouse_position_relative = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
        Point mouse_screen_position = popup.PointToScreen(mouse_position_relative);
        private void OnMouseLostCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        bool gotcapture = this.CaptureMouse();
        this.textblock.Text = "lost capture.";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

What exactly was your problem?
Wait! There **is** a way to position a Popup relative to the screen. see [PlacementMode.AbsolutePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.placementmode.aspx)
This showed little happy face flying around:

```
private Popup _popup;

public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _popup = new Popup
              {
                  Child = new TextBlock {Text = "=))", Background = Brushes.White},
                  Placement = PlacementMode.AbsolutePoint,
                  StaysOpen = true,
                  IsOpen = true
              };
    MouseMove += MouseMoveMethod;
    CaptureMouse();
}

private void MouseMoveMethod(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var relativePosition = e.GetPosition(this);
    var point= PointToScreen(relativePosition);
    _popup.HorizontalOffset = point.X;
    _popup.VerticalOffset = point.Y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I realized there is no way to position a Popup relative to the screen, only relative to the Visual which contains it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to get the screen coordinates of the mouse position outside of a WPF `Window`. Unfortunately, you'll need to add references to use either of them, but it *is* possible. You can find examples of them both in @FredrikHedblad's answer to the [How do I get the current mouse screen coordinates in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226740/how-do-i-get-the-current-mouse-screen-coordinates-in-wpf) question. Coincidentally, that question was answered a few days before you asked this question and gave up within 21 minutes of asking.