# Getting the clicked mouse coordinates from a Image Box in C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In order to work with an image I need to make the user select certain(4) coordinates within a Image Box and afterwards save that coordinate data and close the window. The project is using C# and WPF. Sadly google is giving me a lot of unfocused solutions on this topic. Any suggestions/ links?

thanks

Comment: have you looked at this older post on SO?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226740/how-do-i-get-the-current-mouse-coordinates-in-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Point pos = Mouse.GetPosition(myElement);` will give you the mouse position relative to the element.

Comment: Okay, so I do:  `private void Control1_MouseClick(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { Point pos = Mouse.GetPosition(myElement); }` ? But won't the mouse move after the click, and be at another position while my event is still firing off?

Comment: It will. Your mouse will always move and be at different positions. At what time do you want the positions captured?

Comment: at the precise moment of the click

Comment: Use the event MouseLeftButtonDown, and get the position from e.GetPosition(element)