# How to get the mouse position on the screen in Qt?

Tags: qt, qtgui

I want to get the mouse coordinates on the screen.

How can I do this in Qt?

---

On Windows, using C# I was doing something like suggested in the answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737665/1420197).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the docs state: -

```
QCursor::pos()
```

> Returns the position of the cursor (hot spot) of the primary screen in
>   global screen coordinates.

If you have multiple screens, you can use: -

```
QPoint QCursor::pos(const QScreen * screen)
```

Note that QScreen is for Qt 5

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
QCursor::pos()
```

should work perfectly