# Qt 5, get the mouse position in a screen

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, multiscreen

First of all, I'd like to mention that I found that related post [How to get the mouse position on the screen in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523375/how-to-get-the-mouse-position-on-the-screen-in-qt) but it "just didn't work" for me. I made some tests, and the results didn't work as I expected, so I decided to make a new post to talk about the test I made and to find an alternative solution.

That's the code I used to make the test:

```
QScreen *screen0 = QApplication::screens().at(0);
QScreen *screen1 = QApplication::screens().at(1);

printf("screen0 %s \n", screen0->name().toStdString().c_str());
printf("screen1 %s \n", screen1->name().toStdString().c_str());

// Position on first screen.
QPoint pos0 = QCursor::pos(screen0);

// Position on second screen.
QPoint pos1 = QCursor::pos(screen1);

printf("pos 0: %d, %d \n", pos0.x(), pos0.y());
printf("pos 1: %d, %d \n", pos1.x(), pos1.y());

// Get position without screen.
QPoint pos = QCursor::pos();
printf("pos: %d, %d \n", pos.x(), pos.y());
```

What I was expecting, is that only one screen would return a valid position, since the cursor is only at one screen, not on both. But it's not the case, the both positions (`pos0` and `pos1`) has the exactly same value, as we can see on the output:

```
screen0 DVI-D-0 
screen1 HDMI-0 
pos 0: 1904, 1178 
pos 1: 1904, 1178 
pos: 1904, 1178
```

Since the both positions has the same values, I can't know at which screen is the cursor. I don't know if that's a normal behavior or a bug, since the documentation doesn't say what happens when the screen argument isn't the screen where the mouse is.

My idea, is to open/launch an application (executed by a Qt daemon that must detect the selected screen) to the screen where the mouse is. I know that with *libX11* it's possible, because I did it in the past, but I need to work with Qt 5, and I can't figure out how to do detect the selected screen with Qt.

I also made other tests, using `QApplication` and `QDesktopWidget` classes with no luck.

Comment: Are you using a virtual desktop? A dual head?

Answer (score 18):

That's really weird. As a workaround, you could try this:

```
QPoint globalCursorPos = QCursor::pos();
int mouseScreen = qApp->desktop()->screenNumber(globalCursorPos);
```

Now you know which screen the cursor is in. Then you could find the cursor position within that screen doing this:

```
QRect mouseScreenGeometry = qApp->desktop()->screen(mouseScreen)->geometry();
QPoint localCursorPos = globalCursorPos - mouseScreenGeometry.topLeft();
```

Comment: I tried that, but it allways returns the screen 0. Even if you take the point from the screen1 (with pos(QScreen*)), it returns 0.

Comment: I'm using Getoo, with KDE and Awesome as window manager. Maybe that's a configuration problem. Rafael, could you share the output and the code you executed?

Comment: Perhaps it's a Qt bug. Just FYI: I tried what you did in your question and it also didn't work on Windows. I was getting the same coordinate values on pos(QScreen*), regardless on which screen it was given and where the cursor was. Sorry I can't help more than that.

Comment: Your solution worked for me. And you are right `QCursor::pos(QScreen*)` appears to not work correctly (still).

Answer (score 7):

This may seem like a trivial solution, but on my KDE it works (I ran into the same problems originally).
If you want to determine the local mouse coordinates with respect to a widget (this will be in device pixels and relative to the top left corner of the widget I believe) you can use

```
QWidget::mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos());
```

i.e. call `this->mapFromGlobal`.

Answer (score 2):

This may work for you? 
It did for me

`QDesktopWidget *widget           = QApplication::desktop();
 QPosition globalCursorPosition   = widget->cursor().pos();`

Answer (score 1):

To figure out on which screen you are, you can iterate throught [`QGuiApplication::screens()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#screens) and check whether the cursor fits in the [geometry](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#geometry-prop) of the screen.

Here is a more complex example to compute the native cursor position (note the additional work needed to work with High DPI screens):

```
QPoint getNativeCursorPosition()
{
    QPoint pos = cursorPosToNative(QCursor::pos());

    // Cursor positions from Qt are calculated in a strange way, the offset to
    // the origin of the current screen is in device-independent pixels while
    // the origin itself is native!

    for (QScreen *screen : QGuiApplication::screens()) {
        QRect screenRect = screen->geometry();
        if (screenRect.contains(pos)) {
            QPoint origin = screenRect.topLeft();
            return origin + (pos - origin) * screen->devicePixelRatio();
        }
    }

    // should not happen, but try to find a good fallback.
    return pos * qApp->devicePixelRatio();
}
```

Comment: in this code, I believe cursorPos should be renamed pos.

Comment: Which header do I need for this `cursorPosToNative` function - it doesn't seem to exist within Qt 5.9.3?

Comment: @Vertigo There should be a platform-independent way to calculate that, but for simplicity I did not implement that and instead queried the native APIs directly. See for example https://github.com/KDE/spectacle/commit/a41e83edbaadd27cd8ea85d4dfa375033e8ade84#diff-d0fc42a0f2e357991342776195467997R700

Answer (score 0):

Sice it seems that it can't be done with Qt (at least with my system configuration, and it seems that also in Windows) I decided to use the libX11 to make that implementation, which works like charm.

It's not an ideal solution because I wanted to only use Qt, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

With QML you can use the properties of the Screen QML Type:

Screen.virtualX : The x coordinate of the screen within the virtual desktop.

Screen.virtualY : The y coordinate of the screen within the virtual desktop.

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

console.log("Pos x : " + Screen.virtualX )
console.log("Pos y : " + Screen.virtualY )
```

This work with single screen as well multi-monitor systems.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar problem on Qt 5.15 + Windows + mixed DPI and needed this work around within a QWindow object.

```
QScreen* primaryScreen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
QScreen* thisScreen = screen();
qreal primaryDPR = primaryScreen->devicePixelRatio();
qreal thisDPR = thisScreen->devicePixelRatio();
qreal scale = thisDPR / primaryDPR;
QPoint pos = scale  * QCursor::pos();
```

I'm unsure if this works on other platforms.