# How can I get cursor position when I click on my InfoWidget from method mousePressEvent?

Tags: c++, qt, mouse-position

I have main widget MainWindow, that contain my InfoWidget
and InfoWidget has method mousePressEvent

```
void CustomWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPoint p1 = QCursor::pos(); //I get global coordinates (570, 300);
    QPoint p1 = event->pos(); //I get (20, 50) - relative to my InfoWidget
}
```

my qt program

[image]

How can I get cursor position relatively to MainWindow (270, 200) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt 5, get the mouse position in a screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040202/qt-5-get-the-mouse-position-in-a-screen)

Comment: CustomWidget is InfoWidget?

Comment: yes, Infowidget- is my custom widget

Comment: Do you only want the position of InfoWidget regarding MainWindow or do you want the position of any widget regarding MainWindow?

Comment: I want the cursor position regarding to MainWindow

Comment: see my solution