# Set the cursor to go to the other border of the screen if it goes into one in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, cursor

I'm currently developing a 3D viewer application in WPF, and for ergonomy reasons I want my mouse to go to the other border of the screen if it goes into one.

For example, if my mouse goes into the top screen border, set I set my mouse position to the bottom of my screen.
Same for left/right.

How can I actually detect my mouse position in WPF? The only position I can get is related to the software and not the entire screen.

Also, it would be great if it could support dual monitors. (So the mouse is re-set only if it goes into the second monitor)

Answer (score 0):

based on the informative answers to the s.o. question here:

[How do I get the current mouse screen coordinates in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226740/how-do-i-get-the-current-mouse-screen-coordinates-in-wpf)

I think the simpler way to go is the windows.forms method, unless your 3d graphics are updating a lot of computation and you don't want the extra .net unboxed loop performance margin hit.  According to this msdn reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx

the Cursor.Position property is settable, so should be settable from WPF app, although you want to do some research and testing before committing to a lot of code on that

Comment: Problem is that, when I print the position of my cursor, the position when it's at the very top of the screen is Y=101 instead of 0... I don't get it.

Comment: that might happen in dual-screen situations where the two monitor tops are not situated exactly adjacent

Comment: I indeed use dual-screen and my two monitor are perfectly adjacent (Both monitors are the same).

Comment: I don't know about WPF, perhaps something like a toolbar or taskbar is causing the offset