# Converter of System.Drawing.Point' to 'System.Windows.Point

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, valueconverter

I am trying to draw few entities in WPF. My collection contains System.Drawing.Rectangle objects, When I try to access the location of those objects in WPF XAML I am getting following error

> Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'System.Drawing.Point' and 'System.Windows.Point'. Consider using Converter property of Binding

I know I have to use some valueconverter. Could you please guide me how to convert System.Drawing.Point' to'System.Windows.Point?

**Update:**

Following code gives some exception

```
public class PointConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        System.Windows.Point pt = (Point)(value);
        return pt;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<PathFigure StartPoint= "{Binding BoundingRect.Location, Converter={StaticResource PointConverter}}">
```

Comment: Why negative votes guys? let me know, I can correct it in future

Comment: I was the downvoter, now removed. Reason is you haven't shown your attempt and just asking like give me the code. After your edit question looks fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you'd have got `InvalidCastException`, you can't just cast one type to another unless implicit or explicit conversion exist between them. Remember cast is different and convert is different. Following code converts `System.Drawing.Point` to `System.Windows.Point` and viceversa.

```
public class PointConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        System.Drawing.Point dp = (System.Drawing.Point)value;
        return new System.Windows.Point(dp.X, dp.Y);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        System.Windows.Point wp = (System.Windows.Point) value;
        return new System.Drawing.Point((int) wp.X, (int) wp.Y);
    }
}
```

---

If the `System.Drawing.Point` comes from a Windows Forms mouse event, such as a click event, a `System.Drawing.Point` can't be directly converted to `System.Windows.Point` in this way, since the coordinate systems of each may differ. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19790851/815724 for more information.