# HelpEventArgs MousePos.X is always 0

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to handle Help event in a WinForm application. When user clicks "?" button followed by clicking on a Control inside the Form, the HelpRequested event fires. In the handler from the HelpEventArgs I can get the mouse position relative to the Form, then use Form.PointToClient() function to get the child Control that is clicked. If the Control has children, then I can continue to use the Control.GetChildAtPoint() with the relative position until I get the leaf Control. I use .NET 3.5 in the project.

This worked fine in a complex commercial application. But recently I tried to use a simple WinForm example application show the concept in order to ask other questions, the above procedures does not work well. The HelpEventArgs.MousePos.X is always 0 when the event handler is invoked. Thus the Control I got using the position is null.

Here is the example program (when first click on "?" button, then click on "button", the HelpEventRequested event is fired, but the HelpEventArgs.MousePos.X is always 0):

```
//
//Please add into project the reference to (right click the project and select "Add Reference"):
// WindowsBase
// WindowsFormsIntegration
// PresentationCore
// PresentationFramework
//

//Begin of Form1.cs
//
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      static extern IntPtr GetFocus();


      public Form1()
      {

         InitializeComponent();

         System.Windows.Controls.Button b = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
         b.Content = "WPF_Button";
         b.Name = "WPF_Button_name";
         Grid.SetColumnSpan(b, 1);
         Grid.SetRow(b, 0);

         Grid g = new Grid();
         g.Name = "WPF_Grid";
         g.Children.Add(b);

         this.elementHost1.Child = g;

      }

      // More usefull version of GetChildAtPoint
      public static System.Windows.Forms.Control FindChildAtPoint(System.Windows.Forms.Control parent, System.Drawing.Point pt, ref string path, out System.Drawing.Point relative_point_inside_child)
      {
         //Find a child
         System.Windows.Forms.Control child = parent.GetChildAtPoint(pt);
         //If no child, this is the control at the mouse cursor
         if (child == null)
         {
            path += parent.Name;
            //Offset our current position to be relative to the child to get the point inside the child.
            relative_point_inside_child = new System.Drawing.Point(pt.X, pt.Y);
            return parent;
         }
         path += parent.Name + "\\";
         //If a child, offset our current position to be relative to the child
         System.Drawing.Point childPoint = new System.Drawing.Point(pt.X - child.Location.X, pt.Y - child.Location.Y);
         //Find child of child control at offset position
         return FindChildAtPoint(child, childPoint, ref path, out relative_point_inside_child);
      }


      private void Form1_HelpRequested(object sender, HelpEventArgs e)
      {
         if (System.Windows.Forms.Control.MouseButtons == MouseButtons.None)
         {
            //No mouse activity, this function is entered because of F1 key press.
            //Get the focused Control. If no focused Control then launch overall Help-Window.
            //
            IntPtr handle = GetFocus();
            if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
               System.Windows.Forms.Control ctl = System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle(handle);
               //Got the ctl, do whatever
            }
         }
         else
         { // Help Button ? pressed (After click ?, the mouse cursor changes to ?, 
            // Then user can move the mouse to a UI Control and click it, in this case,
            // we need find the control that is clicked, the control might not be focused
            // in such case.
            // Convert screen coordinates to client coordinates
            System.Drawing.Point pt = this.PointToClient(e.MousePos);
            //Look for control user clicked on
            System.Drawing.Point relative_point_inside_child;
            string path = "";
            System.Windows.Forms.Control ctl = FindChildAtPoint(this, pt, ref path, out relative_point_inside_child);

            if (ctl is ElementHost)
            {
               // This is a WPF view embedded in WinForm, get the root Control
               UIElement wpf_root = (ctl as ElementHost).Child;
               if (wpf_root != null)
               {
                  System.Windows.Point pt_WPF = new System.Windows.Point(relative_point_inside_child.X, relative_point_inside_child.Y);
                  HitTestResult htr = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(wpf_root, pt_WPF);
                  if (htr.VisualHit != null)
                  {
                     //IInputElement elem = System.Windows.Input.Mouse.DirectlyOver;
                     string pathWPF = "";
                     if (htr.VisualHit is DependencyObject)
                     {
                        FindPathOfControlWPF(htr.VisualHit, ref pathWPF);
                     }
                     if (pathWPF == "")
                     {
                        path = path + pathWPF;
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
            e.Handled = true;
         }

      }


      //WPF version of More usefull version of FindPathOfControl
      public static System.Windows.DependencyObject FindPathOfControlWPF(System.Windows.DependencyObject child, ref string path)
      {
         //Find a parent
         System.Windows.DependencyObject parent
            = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

         if (child is System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock)
         {
            path = (child as System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock).Text + path;
         }
         else if (child is System.Windows.Controls.Label)
         {
            path = (child as System.Windows.Controls.Label).Content.ToString() + path;
         }
         else if (child is System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase)
         {
            path = (child as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase).Content.ToString() + path;
         }

         if (child is System.Windows.FrameworkElement)
         {
            path = (child as System.Windows.FrameworkElement).Name + path;
         }

         //If no parent, this is the top control
         if (parent == null)
         {
            return child;
         }
         path = "\\" + path;
         //Find parent of child control
         return FindPathOfControlWPF(parent, ref path);
      }

   }
}
//End of Form1.cs

//Begin of Form1.Designer.cs
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   partial class Form1
   {
      /// <summary>
      /// Required designer variable.
      /// </summary>
      private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

      /// <summary>
      /// Clean up any resources being used.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
      protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
      {
         if (disposing && (components != null))
         {
            components.Dispose();
         }
         base.Dispose(disposing);
      }

      #region Windows Form Designer generated code

      /// <summary>
      /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
      /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
      /// </summary>
      private void InitializeComponent()
      {
         this.flowLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
         this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
         this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
         this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
         this.elementHost1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost();
         this.flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
         this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
         this.panel2.SuspendLayout();
         this.SuspendLayout();
         // 
         // flowLayoutPanel1
         // 
         this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
         this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
         this.flowLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 33);
         this.flowLayoutPanel1.Name = "flowLayoutPanel1";
         this.flowLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(242, 205);
         this.flowLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
         this.flowLayoutPanel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
         // 
         // panel1
         // 
         this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
         this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
         this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
         this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 134);
         this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
         this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
         // 
         // button1
         // 
         this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 39);
         this.button1.Name = "button1";
         this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 35);
         this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
         this.button1.Text = "button1";
         this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
         this.button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
         // 
         // panel2
         // 
         this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.elementHost1);
         this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(99, 3);
         this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
         this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(136, 174);
         this.panel2.TabIndex = 1;
         this.panel2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
         // 
         // elementHost1
         // 
         this.elementHost1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
         this.elementHost1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
         this.elementHost1.Name = "elementHost1";
         this.elementHost1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(136, 174);
         this.elementHost1.TabIndex = 0;
         this.elementHost1.Text = "elementHost1";
         this.elementHost1.Child = null;
         // 
         // Form1
         // 
         this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
         this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
         this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(282, 255);
         this.Controls.Add(this.flowLayoutPanel1);
         this.HelpButton = true;
         this.MaximizeBox = false;
         this.MinimizeBox = false;
         this.Name = "Form1";
         this.Text = "Form1";
         this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
         this.HelpRequested += new System.Windows.Forms.HelpEventHandler(this.Form1_HelpRequested);
         this.flowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
         this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
         this.panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
         this.ResumeLayout(false);

      }

      #endregion

      private System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel1;
      private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
      private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
      private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel2;
      private System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost elementHost1;
   }
}
//End of Form1.Designer.cs
//Begin of Program.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   static class Program
   {
      /// <summary>
      /// The main entry point for the application.
      /// </summary>
      [STAThread]
      static void Main()
      {
         Application.EnableVisualStyles();
         Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
         Application.Run(new Form1());
      }
   }
}
//Enf of Program.cs
```

Comment: Even the example from MSDN has the same issue: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.helprequested%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You need to document your Windows version and list the last updates that were installed.  A workaround is to use Cursor.Position instead.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant! the Cursor.Position works fine.