# Cursors, Point, Differences. C# in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been working on this one bit of code all week and so far have had no answer that fully work around the error I am coming across. The error is on the line `var diff = Cursor.Position - playerPoint;`, this error occurs because you cannot use the (-) operand between a `Windows.Point` and a `Drawing.Point` but the coding to convert it seems to only convert it for the expression it is involved in.

The commented out code is a different attempt at the same method but it produces the same error. Anyone got anything on this?

```
private void tmrMoving_Tick(object sender, object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Drawing.Point dp = (System.Drawing.Point)value;
            var playerPoint = new System.Windows.Point(dp.X, dp.Y);

            var cursPoint = new System.Windows.Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
           // var playerPoint = new System.Windows.Point(player.Location.X, player.Location.Y);
            var diff = Cursor.Position - playerPoint;
            var speed = Math.Sqrt(diff.X * diff.X + diff.Y * diff.Y);
            if (speed > 10)
            {
                diff.X /= speed / 10;
                diff.Y /= speed / 10;
            }
            player.Location += new System.Drawing.Point((int)diff.X, (int)diff.Y);
        }
```

**Edit**
If a method isn't seen through the above code there may be a resolve in the below:

```
private void tmrMoving_Tick(object sender, object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture, EventArgs e)
    {

        var cursPoint = new System.Windows.Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
        var playerPoint = new System.Windows.Point(player.Location.X, player.Location.Y);
        var diff = Cursor.Position - playerPoint;
        var speed = Math.Sqrt(diff.X * diff.X + diff.Y * diff.Y);
        if (speed > 10)
        {
            diff.X /= speed / 10;
            diff.Y /= speed / 10;
        }
        player.Location += new System.Drawing.Point((int)diff.X, (int)diff.Y);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Cursor` is a Windows Forms / GDI+ class, and your use of `System.Windows.Point` indicates you use WPF you have a problem. Those classes are not inter-exchangeable.

If you are using WPF: Instead of `Cursor.Position`, you can use `Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);` as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226740/how-do-i-get-the-current-mouse-screen-coordinates-in-wpf).

If you are using WF: Use `System.Drawing.Point` all the way, not `System.Windows.Point`.

Still, subtracting points isn't possible. You should write this yourself, or better, construct a new point and do the math in the constructor call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74244/discussion-between-ashley-fayers-and-patrick-hofman).

Answer (score 0):

You may calculate the vector from one point to the next directly on the coordinates:

```
int diffX = dp.X - Cursor.Position.X;
int diffY = dp.Y - Cursor.Position.Y;
var speed = Math.Sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffy * diffY);
```

as long as `dp` and `Cursor.Position` use the same coordinate-system i.e. `0,0` means the same for both.