# WPF Thumb drag and move with WindowState.Maximized

Tags: c#, wpf

I have custom window with `WindowState=WindowState.Maximized` with border and thumb inside in the border, it seems that when the `WindowState=WindowState.Maximized` I cannot drag and move the custom window to different screen.

Xaml:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="350"
        Width="525"
        WindowStyle="None">
        <Border Name="headerBorder" 
            Width="Auto" 
            Height="50" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            CornerRadius="5,5,0,0" 
            DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
            Background="Red" 
            BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
            BorderBrush="Yellow">
            <Grid x:Name="PART_Title">
                <Thumb x:Name="headerThumb" 
                    Opacity="0" 
                    Background="{x:Null}" 
                    Foreground="{x:Null}" 
                    DragDelta="headerThumb_DragDelta"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Window>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
    }

    private void headerThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Left = Left + e.HorizontalChange;
        Top = Top + e.VerticalChange;
    }
}
```

I've also overridden `MouseLeftButtonDown` method and using `DragMove()` inside but without success. I've also tried to subscribe to thumb's `MouseLeftButtonDown` and write there `DragMove()` but without success.

Comment: Did you try to use the [WindowChrome](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .NET 4.5? It allows you to have a window without any style and border and be able to manipulate it like a classic window (even in WindowState Maximized).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, maximized windows cannot be moved, thus `Left` and `Top` have no effect. One option would be to register to the `Thumb.DragStarted` event and check if the window is maximized. If yes, you can set `WindowState.Normal` and successively update the `Left` and `Top` properties.

In code, this would look somewhat like this:

```cs
private void Thumb_OnDragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e)
{
    // If the window is not maximized, do nothing
    if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized)
        return;

    // Set window state to normal
    WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

    // Here you have to determine the initial Left and Top values
    // for the window that has WindowState normal
    // I would use something like the native 'GetCursorPos' (in user32.dll)
    // function to get the absolute mouse point on all screens 
    var point = new Win32Point();
    GetCursorPos(ref point);
    Left = point - certainXValue;
    Top = point - certainYValue;

}
```

You can learn more about `GetCursorPos` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226740/how-do-i-get-the-current-mouse-screen-coordinates-in-wpf).

**However, I would strongly advise you to use the [WindowChrome](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome(v=vs.110).aspx) class that comes with .NET 4.5 and that was also suggested by Max in the comments. You just have to use the following code and you have the functionality you're asking for:**

```xml
<Window x:Class="ThumbMaximizedWindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350"
        Width="525"
        WindowStyle="None"
        WindowState="Maximized">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

</Window>
```

Comment: Indeed. You can set the size of the thumb by setting the [CaptionHeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome.captionheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the `WindowChrome`. [CornerRadius](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome.cornerradius%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ResizeBorderThickness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome.resizeborderthickness%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are also interesting.

Comment: I see that the app have strange behaviour, i have 2 monitors, when the app is in maximize mode and dragged to second monitor to maximize mode, the default window buttons is apprears.. its known issue?

Comment: I just tried with the code above (WindowChrome) and I could not reconstruct your problem. The default buttons did not appear when I started dragging on my first monitor, moved the normal window to the next monitor and maximized it there again (all in one go). Did you apply any code that is not in the example above?

Comment: @feO2x Do you know how to fix the window, when maximized, with the <WindowChrome/> solution, the window loses about 4-5px on all sides. So the margins on all sides are incorrect when maximized.

Comment: Also with the <WindowChrome/> tag, when resizing the window, a strange flicker behavior is happening, showing a window behind my window, like the default chrome is trying to show... Any fix for that?

Comment: @JasonStevenson I cannot recreate this problem - nothings flickering on my machines. Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The fix was to change the NonClientFrameEdges attribute from NONE to one of the sides.  That seems to have fixed the problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669632/wpf-windowchrome-causing-flickering-on-resize