# Set mouse position to center of title in borderless window when clicking move in context menu

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, move, drag, drop

I search for a solution to the following problem: For a nice look I use a borderless window, so I have created a title area for this window (it's a `Grid`).

```
  <Grid x:Name="rootGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundColor}" >
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem x:Name="cmiVerschieben" Header="Verschieben" Click="cmiVerschieben_Click"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>
    <!-- ... -->
</Grid>
```

Now I added a context menu to the title bar like the most applications have
(Close, Maximize, Minimize, Move ...).

The simple commands are not a problem, but for the "Move"-Entry I have to move my mouse cursor from the current position to the center of my title grid.

I tried it in `cmiVerschieben_Click` with  `rootGrid.Focus();` and `rootGrid.CaptureMouse();`, but both don't set my cursor to the `rootGrid`.

Why I want to do this? In many other applications when I click the "Move" context menu item, the mouse is moved to the center of the title window.

I removed the unnecessary event handler from my code here.

Comment: Do you mean actual Drag&Drop or click left mouse button and move the Window ?  Drag&Drop is when you Drag an object into that area. eg. dragging a file into your window

Comment: i meen the behavior "click left mouse button and move the window"
at the most other appliciations is therefor a contextmenu entry.
Corrected it at the start post.

Comment: Do you want to move the mouse to the center of of the grid and change icon ?

Comment: For the moving part it self you have to handle the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event and do `this.Drag();`

Comment: Move the mouse to the center of the grid and change the icon is exactly what i need.

How i chan change the icon i already know, MouseLeftButtonDown is implemented to.
It'S only the mouse move which i search

Comment: yes, thanks! used the answer from thatguy, but it is prinicipally the same if you look at the last answer at these link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need some interop code to get and set the current mouse position on screen. Take a look at these related questions as reference: [Get mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226740/how-do-i-get-the-current-mouse-screen-coordinates-in-wpf). [Set mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226740/how-do-i-get-the-current-mouse-screen-coordinates-in-wpf).

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct Win32Point
{
   public int X;
   public int Y;
}

private static Point GetMousePosition()
{
   Win32Point w32Mouse = new Win32Point();
   GetCursorPos(ref w32Mouse);

   return new Point(w32Mouse.X, w32Mouse.Y);
}
```

Then you can calculate the postion difference to your `rootGrid` and set the new mouse position, as well as a different mouse cursor icon.

```
private void CmiVerschieben_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var positionOnRootGrid = Mouse.GetPosition(rootGrid);
   var xDifference = (int)(positionOnRootGrid.X - rootGrid.ActualWidth / 2);
   var yDifference = (int)(positionOnRootGrid.Y - rootGrid.ActualHeight / 2);
   var absoluteMousePosition = GetMousePosition();

   var absoluteXPosition = absoluteMousePosition.X - xDifference;
   var absoluteYPosition = absoluteMousePosition.Y - yDifference;

   // Set the position in the center of the root grid
   SetCursorPos(absoluteXPosition, absoluteYPosition);

   // Set the mouse cursor icon for roorGrid
   rootGrid.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
}
```

Of course, you the have to handle dragging the window and resetting to cursor later.

Comment: exactly what i needed! Thank you!